# Erro conversão base64

Tags: powershell

Bom dia
Estou a tentar fazer a conversão de uma string base 64

```
$b = ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("domain/file")

$c = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($b)
```

mas dá-me o erro

> ```
> Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "A entrada não é uma cadeia de Base-64 válida dado que
> contém um caráter que não é de base 64, mais de dois carateres de preenchimento ou um caráter ilegal entre os
> carateres de preenchimento. "
> At line:1 char:1
> + $c = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($b)
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
> ```

O que é que posso estar a fazer mal?

Obrigado

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e não gerou essa exceção, acredito que o problema está presente no conteúdo da variável $b.

Comment: o conteúdo que utilizou foi um PE ou um bin?

Comment: Foi uma string local que eu mesmo declarei com um conteúdo em base64.

Comment: eu tentei substituir o PE pelo PE na base64 nor formato txt mas continua a não dar

Comment: O problema é com o dado que está tentando converter de `base64` para binário. Poderia o anexar a pergunta.